# How to read excel from aem dam and make it available to download for user

Tags: aem, dam

Please look into image for code reference . Query builder is giving me zero result .
I have uploaded excel file in dam/empexcelfile folder

[image]

[image]

Comment: What;s the issue in it? DAM assets should be accessible to end users OOB without additional configuratoin

Comment: Not getting any result

Comment: getTotalMatches() returning 0

Comment: in your example, /content/dam/empexcelpath, is this excel file url or folder url ?

Comment: folder ulr ..inside this i uploaded excel file

Comment: So if all excel's are below this folder, i recommend to traverse all dam:assets below this folder instead of search.